# Laravel 5.5 Web App and Ionic 3 Mobile App

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic-framework, laravel-5, ionic3

I currently have a web app built on Laravel 5.5 with a MySQL DB and would like to build a Mobile App using Ionic 3/Angular 5.

From what I understand, Ionic needs Firebase as its backend for it to work with sockets (I need event broadcasts and server pushes). My concern is that my Mysql database is fairly complicated with over 120 tables all relationally linked together. Would it still work?

What is the best way for me to implement Ionic 5 with a Mysql DB that is being used by Laravel (with jquery)

Thanks for the guidance.

Answer (score 1):

You need to develop **RESTful Web API** using your `Mysql DB` and `PHP/Laravel`. After that, you can easily consume that `API` through `Ionic 3` app. `Ionic` is just a front-end framework where it can consume any backend services.

`Firebase` has a lot of `BAAS services`. Its `real-time DB` or `cloud firestore` is just another service where we can use it as a database. Since you have your own DB then you don't need firebase database service. But still, you can use other firebase services like `Cloud Messaging` or else as you wish. If you have any other questions about this feel free to ask.

[**All Firebase services are here.**](https://firebase.google.com/products/)

Comment: Problem is: Firebase doesn't offer outbound networking for free users. If you want to test it you have pay. If you want to pay you have to add card but they reject the card and ask for verification blah blah. Customers won't go with this annoying process.

Comment: `If you need to get good service, you need to sacrifice something`. That is the universal law. So just test it and if you're not satisfied then cancel it. @user3449848

Comment: It's up to customers (app buyers). If they find it hard, sales will dramatically decrease and charge-back will trigger often . Firebase should open outbound service for free users with limited bandwidth per month.